# Image Submit Button within a Form

Tags: php, html, web-applications

I have a form that has Submit button in form of an Image. When user clicks the image button, the image button should play the role of submit button.

Code Sample:

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
   <input type="image" name="btn_opentextbox" src="image.png" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Handle Submission:

```
if($_POST['btn_opentextbox'])
{
    //do something
}
```

Surprisingly, the above code used to work perfectly fine in Firefox. However, once i updated my Firefox yesterday, it didn't work at all. I click the button, page gets refreshed and nothing happens. The code also doesn't work in IE.

Note: it works in Chrome.

I want it to work in Firefox, IE, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="Submit Form">
```

and in php you can do this

```
if($_POST['action'] == "Submit Form"){
 do something 
}
```

hope this help.

Comment: Smart one. Will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: First check that the array element `isset()` to avoid `E_NOTICE` messages.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a normal `submit`-button and [use CSS to replace the button's look with an image](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/image-button.html). This should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

for image submit button

php code is

```
    if(isset($_POST['btn_opentextbox_X']) || isset($_POST['btn_opentextbox_Y']))
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The good php code is :

```
<input type='image' src='../images/blanc.gif' width='596' height='35'     onFocus='form.submit' name='btn_opentextbox'/>


    if ($_POST["btn_opentextbox_x"]) && ($_POST["btn_opentextbox_y"])
   {

......
   }
```

Comment: "good php code"? As it stands at the moment, your code will generate an `E_NOTICE` message when the form is not submitted by the image submit button. You should check that the array element `isset()`.

Comment: ...also `$_POST["btn_opentextbox_x"]` could legitimately contain the value `0` and therefore evaluate to false.

Answer (score 2):

Check for `btn_opentextbox_x` or `btn_opentextbox_y` instead. (It is actually `.` not `_` but PHP mangles it).

Some browsers fail to send the *value* for server side image maps, just the co-ordinates.

And you seem to have forgotten the `alt` attribute.

---

Alternatively, use an actual submit button instead of an image map:

```
<button type="submit" name="btn_opentextbox" value="submit"><img src="image.png" alt="Submit"></button>
```

… but note that some versions of IE will send the HTML content instead of the value when it is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple buttons in that form and need to know that the form was submitted?
If there is just a single submit button I suggest using following code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // process form submission
    header('Location: page.php?result=success');
}
```

This way you'll be sure if form was submitted and also avoid double submission if user hits reload button after form was submitted.